# compiling compiling/bundling an external framework to my static library/framework for iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, frameworks

im trying to build a framework that uses methods from a 3rd party framework. 
I would like to hide the methods 3rd party framework from being accessible by the user of my framework.

I tried compiling using static library method and framework method.. but the 3rd party framework doesn't seems to be included in my framework..

any one know how can i bundle the 3rd party framework in my library file?

any help is much much appreciated.

Comment: You should work on your accept-rate. It currently shows 17% -> very low. See the FAQ for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to include a static library or another framework inside an home-made framework. The user will need to add both your framework and a static library (3rd party methods) in its project to be able to use it.

Comment: is there any way to hide the 3rd party methods?

Comment: Actually, it is possible to link a static lib with another static lib. Well, strictly speaking that is not linking but archiving. You could split both libraries into their object files and create a new static library out of both of these using the AR tool.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in having a dependency in your static library / custom framework. Simply inform the user about it and, if possible, bundle the depended library in your distribution.

ObjectiveC does not allow the usage of namespaces, hence there is no way to "hide" the methods of a static library effectively.